# ubuntu on laptop without Intel graphic

Tags: graphics, asus, display-resolution, 16.10, nvidia-geforce

I have bought ASUS ROG GL502VY and it comes with one GPU (Nvidia GeFroce gtx980m 8GB VRAM), I tried installing ubuntu on it, and I succeeded but!

first problem is it only detect 4k display settings and by default it has no 1920x1080 resolution to set, after installing nvidia driver I get nvidia x server settings, when I set resolution on 1920x1080 it zooms into 1/4 of my display and not scale it all.

second problem is that it does not recognize anything related to monitor and graphic, I can't adjust brightness, I can't lower resolution(even after manually add it using xrandr)

Is there anyway to get my laptop working with ubuntu without the Intel GPU and only with installed Nvidia or I should just give up!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work! and It was really easy!

just from additional drivers I didn't download the proprietary driver for Nvidia and used the open source option available.

then from the settings I get all the things I wanted to adjust.

for brightness I haven't found anything inside the system settings, I just downloaded the app "Brightness Controller" and I user that (which is not really helpful, but does the job)